# Navigate/select ag-grid table row with arrow keys

Tags: reactjs, navigation, ag-grid

I'm trying to navigate the rows of an ag-grid table on a react app. This means when I press up or down, the current selected row changes to the previous/next row.

I've tried the example on the [ag-grid docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-selection/#example-selection-with-keyboard-arrow-keys). But I don't know how to access the gridOptions.
How would I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way, although I'm using useRef and I'd prefer to avoid it.

This is the main function:

```
const arrowKeysNavigation = (tableRef) => (params) => {
  var previousCell = params.previousCellPosition;
  var suggestedNextCell = params.nextCellPosition;
  const api = tableRef.current.api;

  var KEY_UP = 38;
  var KEY_DOWN = 40;
  var KEY_LEFT = 37;
  var KEY_RIGHT = 39;

  switch (params.key) {
    case KEY_DOWN:
      previousCell = params.previousCellPosition;
      // set selected cell on current cell + 1
      api.forEachNode(function (node) {
        if (previousCell.rowIndex + 1 === node.rowIndex) {
          node.setSelected(true);
        }
      });
      return suggestedNextCell;
    case KEY_UP:
      previousCell = params.previousCellPosition;
      // set selected cell on current cell - 1
      api.forEachNode(function (node) {
        if (previousCell.rowIndex - 1 === node.rowIndex) {
          node.setSelected(true);
        }
      });
      return suggestedNextCell;
    case KEY_LEFT:
    case KEY_RIGHT:
      return suggestedNextCell;
    default:
      throw new Error(
        "this will never happen, navigation is always one of the 4 keys above"
      );
  }
};
```

The main steps:

1. Create ref `const tableRef = React.useRef();`
2. Associate it to ag-grid together with the function above:

`<AgGridReact ... ref={tableRef} navigateToNextCell={arrowKeysNavigation(tableRef)}/>`